# Getting Selenium WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page only on deployed code

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, digital-ocean

I've been struggling for days to deploy a Selenium scraping bot, but I can't wrap my head around an error I'm encountering. Locally, the scraping bot runs perfectly, whether in headless mode or with a graphical interface, executing all necessary steps without issues. However when trying it deployed obviously only with headless mode the bot runs smoothly until it attempts to driver.get() on a specific website, resulting in a timeout. The project is fully dockerized, making deployment steps very simple. I've utilized Digital Ocean Cloud for deployment.

Initially, I attempted deployment on an Ubuntu 22.04 Droplet by cloning the repository, installing Docker, and running 'docker compose up --build'and everything worked. The bot ran until it attempted driver.get() on a specific website, resulting in a timeout. I captured a screenshot of the website after the driver.get() call, and it displayed as a plain blank page. This time was using the Chrome webdriver. Switching to the Firefox webdriver produced the same result, except this time, instead of timing out, I encountered this specific error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https%3A//subdomain.someweb.com/&c=UTF-8&d=The%20connection%20to%20subdomain.someweb.com%20was%20interrupted%20while%20the%20page%20was%20loading.

I also tried with Debian 12 using both Chrome and Firefox, with same results. It's crucial to note:

- Before the bot fails, it navigates to another website, and that flow runs fine. Therefore, I suspect the issue is related to this specific website.
- I printed the UserAgent both locally and in deployment, and they are identical, ruling out a UserAgent-related problem

So, the question is: why does this website allow access when running locally but not when accessed from this deployed VM?

PS: Sorry if I'm asking poorly; this is my first time asking on StackOverflow and English isn't my mother tongue so please bear with me.